# Question about a near $\Bbb{Z}$-semimodule that has trivial addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, semigroups

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimodule

Suppose that we have a structure $M$ that has:

1. Closure under addition.
2. Closure under multiplication by any $a \in\Bbb{Z}$.
3. The addition of any two elements is constant: $x + y = c \in M$ for some fixed constant.
4. (Doesn't necessarily have) a neutral element.  If it does have a neutral element then (3) doesn't apply to adding $0$ i.e. $0 + x = x = c$ is not necessary  unless $x = c$.

Then can we conclude that $M$ is isomorphic to the trivial module?

Comment: If $M$ has a neutral element $0$ then it seems that $x=0+x=c$ for any $x\in M$.

Comment: @CaptainLama no guarantee of neutral element. -_-

Comment: Ok, you should specify that in your question then, since your link defines a semimodule as an additive monoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current rules, $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a nontrivial example: since $0$ is excluded from rule 3, the only sum that rule 3 applies to is $1+1 = 0$.

Generalizing this, we can have  $M = \{0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ with $0 + x_i = x_i + 0 = x_i$ and $x_i + x_j = 0$ for all $i,j$. Let $m0 = 0$ for all $m \in \mathbb Z$. Let $m x_i = 0$ for even $m$ and $mx_i = x_i$ for odd $m$.

If there is no neutral element (and so rule 3 applies to any sum of elements), then for any $x\in M$, $x = 1x = (0+1)x = 0x+1x = c$, so $M$ is trivial.

Comment: What if  c isn't zero? Also please proof read I see two mistakes

Comment: Also what if the scalars are restricted to act as $ zm= m +m+...+m$?

Comment: @BananaCats Please begin bringing up my mistakes when you learn how to spell "proofread". If you really cared to improve my answer, you'd point them out; saying "ha ha you made a typo I won't tell you where" really doesn't make me want to help you any further.